# Allowing the www user access to a folder in my home folder [OSX]

Tags: mac-osx, permissions

Simple permissions question.

I want the www user to have read write access to a subfolder in my home folder. Obviously, I want to be able to use it too!

I know I can execute:

```
sudo chown -R www:www /Users/myusername/subfolder
```

But I fear that that will mean that www owns it, rather than me. How do I make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the group ownership and not the user.

sudo chown -R :www instead of sudo chown -R www:www. Note that the colon stays.

Comment: `chgrp -R www` also works for changing group, and has simpler syntax.